# Magento2 how to update order summary in checkout when choosing a different shipping method

Tags: magento2, checkout, subtotal, shipping-charges

I'd like to **update shipping price** and **cart subtotal** when choosing a **different shipping method** in the checkout page

[image]

Any hint on involved files and the right approach would be very helpful

Comment: Are you adding a new shipping method or something similar?

Comment: No, only default shipping methods involved, one with price and the other free, when choosing the 5€ one the subtotal should be updated to 105€

Comment: @SantiBM Did you solved ? if yes then please answer here so that it helps us

Comment: Hi @sumeetbajaj, didn't solve it yet!

Comment: @SantiBM have you found a solution to this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

I've finally done it like this:

- Create a `require-config.js` file in `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/requirejs-config.js`

**require-config.js**

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total': {
                'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total-mixin': true
            },
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/shipping': {
                'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/shipping-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

- Add the defined files in `require-config.js` which are:
  `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/summary/abstract-total-mixin.js`

**abstract-total-mixin.js**

```
define([], function () {
    'use strict';

    return function (Component) {
        return Component.extend({
            isFullMode: function () {
                if (!this.getTotals()) {
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    };
});
```

`app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/summary/shipping-mixin.js`

**shipping-mixin.js**

```
define([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/estimate-service'
], function (estimateService) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
        }
    };

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```